# SQL returning rows duplicated

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been developing an extremely basic feed system within my website which (is supposed to) display all the posts where:

1. The posts are not from the logged in user
2. They are all from friends
3. And are ordered by `post_id` (to get the most recent ones first)

One problem I am having with my **SQL** though, is that when querying the database **tables** to grab the rows, it will return one post, but it'll be posted by **all** users, instead of just the one person that created it.

For example, if user `1` posted the status `"Hi"`, and there are 5 users in the database; it'll grab that post, then print it to the page 5 times, along with each individual user as the poster. (See below for image example)

**SQL**:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.*, friends.* 
FROM posts, users, friends
WHERE posts.poster <> ? 
AND users.user_id = posts.poster
AND friends.areFriends = 1 AND (friends.userA = ? AND friends.userB = posts.poster) 
OR friends.areFriends = 1 AND (friends.userA = posts.poster AND friends.userB = ?)
ORDER BY posts.post_id desc LIMIT 20
```

For reference:

`posts.poster` is the person who created the post
`users.user_id` is the id of the same person
`friends.areFriends` 0 = not a friend, 1 = friend
`friends.userA` / `friends.userB` is the logged in user or the friend that that user is friends with (if that makes sense)

[image: Bug Image]

I have tried every possible combination of things that I know to fix the problem, however I'm still new to *"advanced"* **SQL** and can't seem to find anything

I've attempted to explain my problem as best I can, so hopefully someone can help me. I've been trying for the last couple of days to fix it but to no avail,

Cheers.

Comment: Use SQL JOINS ...

Comment: @AmanKumar pretty cryptic for a _n00b_ haha

Comment: To the person who voted for close; please explain how I may improve my question to narrow it down for you :) I feel as if I have made it as clear as I possibly could, but I'm all open for suggestions!

Comment: @Jibin should post that as an answer buddy! :D

Comment: @GROVER Ok.Am sory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classic way of making inner joins is more readable and helps you to understand why the code does not work. Also, it is kind of code convention for SQL, so it also helps other people (like me) to understand you.

I have re-wrote your code to use `INNER JOIN`. Try this out.

```
SELECT @userId := ?;

SELECT posts.*, users.*, friends.* 
FROM friends
JOIN users ON users.user_id = 
    CASE friends.userA
    WHEN @userId
    THEN friends.userB
    ELSE friends.userA END
JOIN posts ON posts.poster = users.user_id
WHERE friends.userA = @userId OR friends.userB = @userId
ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Make sure that there are no dupes in `friends` table. Following query will help you with this:

```
SELECT User1, User2, COUNT(*) as DupeCount
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN friends.userA < friends.userB THEN friends.userA ELSE friends.userB END AS User1,
        CASE WHEN friends.userA < friends.userB THEN friends.userB ELSE friends.userA END AS User2
    FROM friends
) AS F
GROUP BY User1, User2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this out! :) any reason as to why I need to declare userId as an INT?

Comment: @GROVER No, I've just created a variable to stop using `?` everywhere. Type does not matter.

Comment: Oh, that's really smart! :D thanks, that'll definitely help

Comment: I've tried using this as my SQL when querying the database, however it says the query does not execute correctly :/ Would there be any reason for this? I also noticed it doesn't format in sublime like it usually would (I.e: `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE` e.t.c; do not become colored)

Comment: **UPDATE**: I've noticed when removing `DECLARE @userId INT = ?;` from my query, the formatting works.

Comment: @GROVER You need to put a real value instead of `?`

Comment: Haha yes, I do know that, I am using parameterised queries to substitute the `?` with the value of the logged in user.

Comment: @GROVER The answer is updated. Usually, I'm working with T-SQL, so I used a wrong syntax for MySql.

Comment: Awesome! The stuff semi-works, however now I am getting errors when trying to output the returned data? Any idea? :/ 

Assuming I do `foreach($stmt->results() as $post){ echo $post->postid }`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be because of your `where` conditions. Change it like this:

```
WHERE posts.poster <> ? 
AND users.user_id = posts.poster
AND friends.areFriends = 1 
AND ((friends.userA = ? AND friends.userB = posts.poster) OR (friends.userA = posts.poster AND friends.userB = ?))
```

As you wrote the conditions, it will return the rows that fulfill all other conditions OR `friends.areFriends = 1 AND (friends.userA = posts.poster AND friends.userB = ?)`. So even the rows that don't fulfill `users.user_id = posts.poster` will be returned. But as I wrote the conditions, the OR is enclosed in a parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this out! 

Mind telling me how this works, and how it's different from mine? :) Just so I can learn from it in the future

Comment: Answers which are code only and do not explain what has been fixed/improved are not that helpful, Saeed.

Comment: I improved my answer

Comment: Saeed, the duplication is due to not joining the tables together correctly.  It is a very common error.

Comment: It is safer and would avoid these problems using a `JOIN` instead of implementing it by the condition `users.user_id = posts.poster`, but it can be done this way too

Answer (score 1):

I assume the query must return posts of the friends of the user `?`. First find friends, the their posts, then their other data.

```
SELECT  pp.*, uu.* 
FROM     (select distinct case when ? = friends.userB then friends.userA else friends.userB end as user_id
         from friends 
         where ? in (friends.userA, friends.userB)
         and friends.areFriends = 1 
         ) f
join posts pp on pp.poster = f.user_id
join users uu on uu.user_id = pp.poster
```